# Type that depends on generic argument as value argument to function

Tags: typescript

I have a generic type `Group` that looks like this:

```
// K -> Key
// I -> Input
type Group<K, I> = {
    key: K;
    func: (i: I) => void;
};
```

There is a fixed number of `Group` values which I declared in an object like this:

```
const GROUPS = {
    "a": {
        func: (i: {x: number}) => { console.log(i); },
        key: "a",
    },
    "b": {
        func: (i: { y: number }) => { console.log(i) },
        key: "b"
    }
} as const;
```

I then have 2 utility types to refer to all the possible group keys and all the possible group inputs:

```
type GroupKey = keyof typeof GROUPS;
type GroupInput<K extends GroupKey> = Parameters<typeof GROUPS[K]["func"]>[0];

// GroupValue test:
type TestType = GroupInput<"b">; // { y: number}, this works
```

Finally, I have a function that receives both a group key and a group input:

```
function test<K extends GroupKey>(key: K, input: GroupInput<K>) {
    if (key === "b") {
        (input.y); // Why doesn't TypeScript understand that `input.y` must be `number` here?
    }
}
```

This function is generic over the type of the key that is passed in and unfortunately, TypeScript cannot "understand" that if `key` is `"b"`, then `input` is of type `{ y: number }`. Why is this the case, what is TypeScript missing to be able to do this? I'd especially like to find a GitHub issue on this (so that I can subscribe to it), but I wasn't able to find one as this type of thing is particularly hard to search for.

[Full Playground URL](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGlQWgPghTAngWAFAlASWnTA7ABwFcAXNExA%20UAcQCcB7IggHnABos4BeUAbzSghoANZIAXBADcg4QDMieAMaSAFAEtJmAJShucAG4N1AExmoAvubRKGeAM4laAJQDyAVQAKAZT39ZQgBEAIaBkgKowlGgCspqmvwAHpJ4RAC2AEbwdBa6%20vygtg4MADbwAHQlDADmGtpSoBbsAdFiiJIhgc2Rwk0tgRlh-j3RMYoqoBrhoO2gqZnZjXlwfIV29qUVVbXqun0jrRKgA4EtFmgWoMH2aw4k1qgUVLSMzOBIfm0McqBP8N8uDw%20cx-F5MAj4YgkNigeCJEjwPAmG70cHvRA8UCeYJ0YJpeAIuj2Fh-AE0NxebwAbXAAF0qYFYkpArSYFSAAy0h4YVHMABqwRKRGoCMc4nIlGoABV4I4pZK-LyIYRSCwTjAGhhVrN5lkcpwSAALdQ3ADuDDoInsaDQTJI6jsv1l0MgcIRSJRrwI6Jgqjakg4oHUKpIkiVkNV4BgugiUXUPz9H24yeOgxjLSiGhD5UQ9VAGAA6obEKATAxZXgAOROeVUbxKOjqAhORQmbKOYJI36G4JOAAGwahOb7oDSREcoCyoD7uuyI8N2XgAH4zhcgA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider this snippet:

```
const key = 'a' as GroupKey
const input = { y: 1 } // optionally cast as GroupInput<'b'> or as GroupInput<GroupKey>

test(key, input) // compiles, but not intended
```

The `input` *might* be independent from the `key`. There are no guarantees `input.y` must be a number when `test` is called with value `'b'` as the first argument.
`type TestType = GroupInput<"b">` uses literal type (`'b'`) which allows Typescript to restrict `'a' | 'b'` to just `'b'`. The same applies for `test('b', ...)`, but passing key of type `'a' | 'b'` allows to pass input of type `GroupInput<'a' | 'b'>`.

One option would be to check if `'y' in input`, but this still does not address the main issue of not allowing wrong arguments to `test`. In general case `input as GroupInput<'b'>` is unsafe and should be avoided at *any* cost.

A possible fix:

```
type Params = { [K in GroupKey]: [key: K, input: GroupInput<K>] } // key: and input: are used for auto-completion instead of generic arg_0, arg_1

function test2(...args: Params[GroupKey]) {
    // const [key, input] = args // will not work
    if (args[0] === "b") {
        const input = args[1];
        input.y; // number
    }
}

test2('b', { y: 1 }) // ok
test2('b', { x: 1 }) // error
test2(key, input) // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGlQWgPghTAngWAFAlASWnTA7ABwFcAXNExA+UAcQCcB7IggHnABos4BeUAbzSghoANZIAXBADcg4QDMieAMaSAFAEtJmAJShucAG4N1AExmoAvubRKGeAM4laAJQDyAVQAKAZT39ZQgBEAIaBkgKowlGgCspqmvwAHpJ4RAC2AEbwdBa6+vygtg4MADbwAHQlDADmGtpSoBbsAdFiiJIhgc2Rwk0tgRlh-j3RMYoqoBrhoO2gqZnZjXlwfIV29qUVVbXqun0jrRKgA4EtFmgWoMH2aw4k1qgUVLSMzOBIfm0McqBP8N8uDw+cx-F5MAj4YgkNigeCJEjwPAmG70cHvRA8UCeYJ0YJpeAIuj2Fh-AE0NxebwAbXAAF0qYFYkpArSYFSAAy0h4YVHMABqwRKRGoCMc4nIlGoABV4I4pZK-LyIYRSCwTjAGhhVrN5lkcpwSAALdQ3ADuDDoInsaDQTJI6jsv1l0MgcIRSJRrwI6Jgqjakg4oHUKpIkiVkNV4BgugiUXUPz9H24yeOgxjLSiGhD5UQ9VAGAA6obEKATAxZXgAOROeVUbxKOjqAhORQmbKOYJI36G4JOAAGwahOb7oDSREcoCyoD7uuyI8N2XgAH4zhcbag0BgoNug-Z7MLQKb1EarhkGAZqOo0gQyvi8CRew68NBtzZ1k42n5K8FK1dPWikDfO4gxDPxtUkABGRp8zABhmyfQUShLJRrica4wWYCNoUrDJKzgC0-ww5UoRYJUfXXUUSETRBOEHUhdAwWxr3UMp7E4DJSDmBgnGDd02xMdctx3AgGD3dQMjKGJ1ESF8oAohVsVxNIbl4VYaRAoj0VpSQqX9CBaJDMMvSwtgYFpaCMD0zsTBAqFJBxahx3gGy5AI4JSAYKAmJvAknxAxx4GCGyAWqRFsnUJQrjoaoAH12U4HFYog9c7T8yiACZVHKbLEvsSRFLxewqTIpBaXTA5GPfUBdKQAyoXM3hcpgw8WJKLinHNS0WnjSZco5BqUxOcrRiEIoJzopxGuioqIK5DNhAmnNNTAWc6FXSwKOdTKcMrThwNAKDcmahgRHILbVB2vbQGSA6lma7JGDWx5zraOr6PuuhHvXIA)

Answer (score 0):

Because the `input` parameter is independent from your `key` parameter. `input` is not required to have `y` as a property although your key might be equal to `'b'`. You would have to Typecast your `input`:

```
 function test<K extends GroupKey>(key: K, input: GroupInput<K>) {
    if (key === "b") {
        const typedInput = input as GroupInput<'b'>;
        (typedInput.y)
    }
}
```

Comment: haven't seen your answer. I have removed my answer.

Comment: Typecasting is not a great solution, it's dangerous, so I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way around this, since you can not ensure that your GroupInput belongs to the same Key.